# Doubt in a problem related to homotopy lifting

Tags: algebraic-topology

This was a problem I came across while studying the proof of Monodromy Theorem.

Let $p: X \to B$ be a covering map (assume $X$ to be path connected). Let $F:I \times I \to B$ be a continuous map ($I$ is the interval $[0,1]$). Let $F(0,0)=b_0$ and let $x_0 \in p^{-1}(b_0)$. Let $\widetilde{F}:I \times I \to X$ be the unique lift given by Homotopy Lifting Property such that $\widetilde{F}(0,0) = x_0$.

- If $F(0,t)=b_0$ for $t \in I$, then $\widetilde{F}(0,t) = x_0$ for $t \in I$.
- If $F(1,t)=b_1$ for $t \in I$ (for some $b_1 \in B$), then there exist a $x_1 \in p^{-1}(b_1)$ such that $\widetilde{F}(1,t) = x_1$ for $t \in I$.

I was able to do the first part using the Path Lifting Property. However I'm stuck at the second part for hours. I tried to something using the paths $F(t,0)$ and $F(t,1)$ but to no avail. I'm not even sure that problem is correct (ie. free of typos).

I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second property is also due to a basic application of path lifting: The path $t \mapsto \tilde{F}(1, t)$ is a lift of $t \mapsto F(1, t)$, so since the latter is constant at $b_1$, the former, too, must be constant at some $x_1 \in p^{-1}(b_1)$.

Comment: Oh. we just have to take $x_1 = \widetilde{F}(1,0)$. I ashamed I missed that.

Comment: @AjinShajiJose Don't be; it happens to the best of us :)